# Glyph origin or any mnemonic for 蕴?

Tags: meaning, etymology, glyph-origin

I failed to remember the meaning for the word 蕴含 yùnhán. Is any mnemonic or story or etymological hints to remember 蕴?

Comment: 蘊含 is a rather difficult word. How did you chance upon this?

Comment: [tag:glyph-origin] questions should be asked one question at a time, unless the characters are actually related.

Comment: Parker it is from the secondary school text book or workbook or from notes. It is part of my flashcard deck. Let me find and copy the Context

Comment: dROOOze, agree with you. I have updated the question to one word 蕴. I will keep a separate question for 含 as these two characters glyph origins are completely different

Comment: If it makes you feel any better - it's still pronounced "*wen*" in some dialects.

Comment: Mou thanks. But at this moment not looking at other dialects.

Comment: @user27485 What I meant was: there are often jokes about dialect speakers being uncouth and backwaterish because their pronunciation is  "unstandard." But the fact that a mnemonic is needed to remember the reading "yun" and that some topolects still pronounce it "*wen*", speaks more to the artificiality of Standard Mandarin rather than anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

蕴 means accumulate.

蕴 is merely a phonetic-semantic character comprising plants 艸 and 缊 which provides sound. 缊 is an obsolete character that means "tangled strings". 缊 itself is silk and sound component  meaning kindness (giving a bowl 皿 of food to a prisoner 囚). None of these characters contribute any meaning to the definition of 蕴.

If you want a sort of mnemonic, I'd use 蕰 instead. 蕰 is one of a variant forms for 蕴. Mnemonics are more difficult to think of if the sound component 缊 isn't a common character. But with 温 (warm) being a more common character, you can think of it as gathering/accumulating vegetables 艸 to keep them warm before eating. Just remember that the standard form is 蕴 and not 蕰.

https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E8%95%B4